# Looking-up the values of one worksheet in another worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Basically, I could do this manually, but as the data is huge, it would take a lot of time. I am sure there must be a formulaic way of doing it.

I have two worksheets in Excel.

Worksheet 1.

```
Column-A        Column-B
Device Names    Total numbers
Device A           19 
Device B           81
Device C           12 
Device D           21 
etc.               etc.
```

Worksheet 2.

```
Column-A         Column-B
Device Names   Total numbers
Device D
Device S
Device Z
Device S
etc.
```

I need the formula which will look-up the Device names in Column-A/Worksheet 2 in ColumnA/Worksheet 1. If the device names in worksheet 2 and worksheet 1 match, the data in Column-B of worksheet-1 should be transferred to Column-B in worksheet-2.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [VLOOKUP()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) function.

In Column-B in Worksheet 2 for row 2 ("Device D"), I'd put something like:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:B4,2, FALSE)`

`A1` is the cell in Worksheet 2 that contains the value you're looking up (on Row 2, it's "Device D")

`Sheet1!A1:B4` names the range in Worksheet 1 that contains the search table

`2` is the column index in the search table, which basically calls out column B in Worksheet 1, as the value to *return* for when the device name (the first column) matches the value in Worksheet 2 for that row.

(*Extremely* common question by the way; this is not a special snowflake problem... You may have been able to easily google something similar.)

Comment: Agree with VLOOKUP but suggest you add FALSE as 4th argument for exact matches only, i.e. `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A$1:B$4,2,FALSE)`

Comment: Agree with VLOOKUP and @barryhoudini . Add the FALSE argument in the VLOOKUP unless you are OK with approximate matches (for most users, most of the time you should add FALSE - otherwise it assumes the search table is organized in ascending order and returns the first value <= to the searched value)

Comment: Updated my answer. If you think the answer needs more explanation about the FALSE, feel free to propose an edit and I'll review it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an INDEX MATCH something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$5,(MATCH($A1,Sheet1!A$2:A$5,0))),-1)
```

Replace the example values with the following:

MATCH(*cell to match from sheet2*, *range to match from sheet1*, 0)

INDEX(*column range containing result you want from sheet1*,

and, change the '-1' to whatever you want to appear in column B, sheet2, if no match is found in sheet1.

Here's a page with a more detailed explanation of this strategy:

[How to Use INDEX MATCH](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)