# if Cell in colum D on worksheet 1 is found in Colum M on Worksheet 2 then return corresponding cell in Column j of Worksheet 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of venues in Column D of Worksheet 1 and I would like to Look up Column M in Woksheet 2 to see if that venue exists. If the Venue exists I would like to take the corresponding value from Column J in woksheet 2 which contains the Venue type

Comment: What have you tried?  I did something similar today, don't have the formula handy, got it off a website during my research

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking-up the values of one worksheet in another worksheet](http://superuser.com/questions/560750/looking-up-the-values-of-one-worksheet-in-another-worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would have tried the `VLOOKUP()` function.
But your data needs to be slightly re-arranged to get the required result.
See the image below.
[image]

What have I done above:

1. In *Worksheet-2* I have copied your *Venue Type* in Column J to another column O. The reason is `VLOOKUP()` function looks for the match in the first column of its table array.
2. Say you need to populate the *Venue Type* data in column F in *Worksheet-1*, then use the formula as shown in the below image.

The `VLOOKUP()` formula is

> =VLOOKUP(D3,M2:O11,3,0)

Just drag the above formula to the rest of the below cells as needed.

Comment: Right idea, but better to use `INDEX(...,MATCH(...))` -- no need to change your worksheet.