# How to attach a value to a unique name

Tags: microsoft-excel

New here and I am unable to find an answer to this.

I am attempting to create a fantasy golf scorer for my local league. 
I have column A set up for each golfer(last name) and column G is that golfers score, on the same row. How can I "attach" the score(in G) to the golfers name in A ? This is on worksheet 2.

I then would like to type each golfers name on sheet 1, in columns, and have the score for that golfer appear in the adjacent column to the right. Can Excel recognize text and assign that text a value(from sheet 2) to an adjacent row On worksheet 1 ?

On sheet 1, each person(row) in my league picks 6 golfers(1 per column). In each row will be a golfer and that golfers score From sheet 2 adjacent to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking-up the values of one worksheet in another worksheet](http://superuser.com/questions/560750/looking-up-the-values-of-one-worksheet-in-another-worksheet)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a reference table like so on the first worksheet:

```
        A            B
1   Golfer1 Name | Golfer1 Score
2   Golfer2 Name | Golfer2 Score
```

etc.

Once all of your golfer/score cells are entered, you can select all of the data in the table and either 1) create a formal table via the `Insert` tab or you can click into the cell dropdown box to the west of the function input field and simply type a name for referencing the table (for this example I will call it 'Golfers')

Ensure you sort the table alphabetically by golfer name.

If you would like to put the golfer's name in cell A1 and see the corresponding score in cell B1, write a function like this in cell B1:

=VLOOKUP(A1, **FirstSheetName!Golfers** ,2,false)  [without these added spaces]

Where:

```
A1 : the cell your lookup is referencing
FirstSheetName! : the name of the workbook you are referencing
Golfers : the name of the table where the left-most column will be searched for that reference.
2 : The number of the column relative to the left-most column in the table ("second column from the left")
false : This is a boolean to choose to use estimation for the lookup. Estimation is rarely used and sometimes wonky to work with. Avoid it.
```

Once this is entered into the first cell of the column, select that cell and find the little black box in the bottom right corner. Mouse-over this box and you'll see your cursor change. When your cursor has changed, click and drag that box downward to propagate that formula to as many cells as you would like to accommodate. The referenced cell in the formula will change to match such so the formula in f.ex. B2 will be:

=VLOOKUP(B2, **FirstSheetName!Golfers** ,2,false)  [without these added spaces]

Answer (score 0):

You want two different things and there's two ways to do it.

First way is a simple vlookup from sheet 2 to sheet1

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$G$5,7,0)
```

This will look up a name in A1, find it on the other sheet and give you the score.

Then you can just use the name and score next to each other as `=A1&A2`

If you want to append the two before you find the match, you can just use the formula above or `=CONCATENATE`.